# Cisco NAT Config for DSL

Tags: cisco, nat

So, we've had the two weeks from hell with a Verizon DSL install -- but after four man days of our time spent, they finally have that working.  But, now I'm struggling with our LAN config.

In short, I have a Verizon DSL connection with 5 static IPs.  I want to NAT most of our machines through 1 static IP, and then the balance of static IPs would be used for public facing devices.

The design is:

Verizon DSL Modem -> Cisco 2600 E1/0 ...
     Cisco 2600 E0/0 -> 24 port managed switch

The 2600's public interface is at `69.24.8.18.`

Below is the config that I currently have tried.

10.20.60.0-255 is the private addresses for the LAN (e0/0). I would like the Cisco to give these out via DHCP. The dns-server `68.94.156.1 68.94.157.1` are good DNS servers. This all looks to be working fine.

`69.24.8.18-22` are our static IPs with Verizon. `69.24.8.1` is the default route through Verizon. Subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`

69.24.8.18 is the 2600 address as I said. `69.24.8.19` is the NAT pool address for 10.20.60.xxx addresses to share -- but I would love to conserve the IPs and make this pool use the same as the router address (69.24.8.18). I think that's possible, right?

192.168.1.1 is the address of the Verizon DSL Router. `192.168.1.10` is the address of the Cisco on that segment for convenience sake.

The switch is where I'd like to plug in all VoIP phones, and computers into ... whether they have a 10.20.60.xxx or have a public address (e.g., `69.24.8.20-22`). Is that doable?

This can't be that hard -- but I'm thinking I'm pretty lame.  Any advice?

---

```
Cisco-2600#wr

Building configuration...

[OK]

Cisco-2600#sho run

Building configuration...



Current configuration : 2126 bytes

!

version 12.1

no service single-slot-reload-enable

service timestamps debug datetime

service timestamps log datetime

service password-encryption

!

hostname Cisco-2600

!

logging buffered 4096 debugging

no logging console

enable secret 5 $1$bNtd$Zc9axgSjxOr4nrts9kJVb/

enable password 7 010109114F0E0B0A

!

!

!

!

!

memory-size iomem 15

clock timezone PST -8

clock summer-time PDT recurring

ip subnet-zero

no ip source-route

ip dhcp excluded-address 10.20.60.1 10.20.60.99

ip dhcp excluded-address 10.20.60.200 10.20.60.254

!

ip dhcp pool dhcp-MainLAN

   network 10.20.60.0 255.255.255.0

   domain-name something.com

   default-router 10.20.60.1

   dns-server 68.94.156.1 68.94.157.1

   lease 0 2

!

no ip bootp server

!

!

!

interface Loopback1

 no ip address

!

interface Ethernet0/0

 description Lakefield Private LAN

 ip address 10.20.60.1 255.255.255.0

 no ip redirects

 no ip proxy-arp

 ip nat inside

 no ip mroute-cache

 half-duplex

 no cdp enable

!

interface Ethernet0/1

 no ip address

 no ip redirects

 no ip mroute-cache

 shutdown

 half-duplex

 no cdp enable

!

interface Ethernet1/0

 description Verizon-DSL

 ip address 69.24.8.18 255.255.255.0

 ip nat outside

 no ip mroute-cache

 half-duplex

 no cdp enable

!

router rip

 network 10.0.0.0

 network 69.0.0.0

!

ip nat pool NAT-Pool 69.24.8.19 69.24.8.19 netmask 255.255.255.0

ip nat inside source list 1 pool NAT-Pool overload

ip classless

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 69.24.8.1

no ip http server

!

logging trap debugging

logging facility local0

access-list 1 permit 10.20.60.0 0.0.0.255

no cdp run

snmp-server engineID local 000000090200003080F34140

snmp-server community RO RO

snmp-server community Cisco-2600 RO

snmp-server community public RO

banner login ^CC

********************************************

*     This is a private network. No        *

*     unauthorized usage without           *

*     permission.  Thank you.              *

********************************************

^C

!

line con 0

 exec-timeout 60 0

 login

line aux 0

line vty 0 4

 exec-timeout 1440 0

 password 7 0519091A3549430C

 login

!

ntp clock-period 17179828

ntp server 192.6.38.127

end
```

Cisco-2600#

Comment: This is kind of a 'do my work for me post'.  Maybe you should state what isn't working in particular?

Answer (score 1):

> This can't be that hard -- but I'm thinking I'm pretty lame. Any advice?

I hate to suggest something non-cisco, but you are running older end of life'd Cisco routers -- so I will.  When my PIX 506e burned up, I replaced it with a tinsy system from [LogicSupply](http://www.logicsupply.com/) running [Vyatta](http://www.vyatta.com/) and have been nothing but impressed.

I just shipped out a production VMWare machine running 6 static IP's, 3 internal networks (10.0.1.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24, 10.0.3.0/24), all natting out of one IP, and all 6 external IP's randomly port forwarding inward with no respect for any one to one mappings.

If you had a spare machine you could replace the 2600 with, or purchase something solid state from LogicSupply -- you would be extremely impressed with Vyatta .. and want to shoot yourself in the foot for using the 2600 for anything but a doorstop.

> password 7 0519091A3549430C

It goes without saying -- but you've posted your private IP's, router, router config, and hashed password online.  Your going to change that password right?

Comment: Yep -- changed the password, and the statics were never the ones listed.

I ended up using simple NAT on this 2600 to work, and all is well now.  It was just a matter of getting it right.

Thanks!

Neil

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up with if anyone needs this for the future...

Current configuration : 3119 bytes

!

version 12.1

no service single-slot-reload-enable

service timestamps debug datetime

service timestamps log datetime

service password-encryption

!

hostname Xplain-2600

!

logging buffered 4096 debugging

no logging console

enable secret [snipped]

enable password [snipped]

!

!

!

!

!

memory-size iomem 15

clock timezone PST -8

clock summer-time PDT recurring

ip subnet-zero

no ip source-route

ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.127

ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.2.192 192.168.2.254

!

ip dhcp pool dhcp-MainLAN

network 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

domain-name xplain.com

default-router 192.168.2.1

dns-server 68.238.96.12 68.238.64.12

lease 0 2

!

no ip bootp server

!

!

!

interface Loopback1

no ip address

!

interface Ethernet0/0

description Lakefield Private LAN

ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0

no ip redirects

no ip proxy-arp

ip nat inside

no ip mroute-cache

half-duplex

no cdp enable

!

interface Ethernet0/1

no ip address

no ip redirects

no ip mroute-cache

shutdown

half-duplex

no cdp enable

!

interface Ethernet1/0

description Verizon-DSL

ip address 98.211.4.130 255.255.255.0

ip nat outside

no ip mroute-cache

half-duplex

no cdp enable

!

ip nat inside source list 1 interface Ethernet1/0 overload

ip nat inside source static 192.168.2.10 98.211.4.131 extendable

ip nat inside source static 192.168.2.22 98.211.4.132 extendable

ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.2.200 407 98.211.4.134 860 extendable

ip classless

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 98.211.4.1

no ip http server

!

logging trap debugging

logging facility local0

access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.128 0.0.0.63

access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.64 0.0.0.63

access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.192 0.0.0.63

access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.63

no cdp run

snmp-server engineID local 000000090200003080F34140

snmp-server community RO RO

snmp-server community Xplain-2600 RO

snmp-server community public RO

banner login ^CC

---

- This is a private network. No        *
- unauthorized usage without           *
- permission.  Thank you.              *

---

^C

!

line con 0

exec-timeout 60 0

login

line aux 0

line vty 0 4

exec-timeout 1440 0

password [snipped]

login

!

ntp clock-period 17179828

ntp server 192.6.38.127

end